# Random access to file bundled with Android apk

Tags: android

Can I have random file access to a file bundled in my Android aplication? I don't want to copy the file from apk to the sdcard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't: [How to get a path to resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681665/how-to-get-a-path-to-resources/3722556#3722556) . If you don't want to copy a file to sdcard, you could read it fully to a memory buffer and work with this buffer.

Answer (score 0):

This response is correct, but there is a workaround:
[RandomAccessFile in Android raw resource file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335379/randomaccessfile-in-android-raw-resource-file)