# Object serialization and random access in java

Tags: java, serialization, random-access

Can you use Java's built in object serialization with a random access file? My motivation is my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10010151/how-to-perform-a-binary-search-of-a-text-file/27682316#27682316).

Comment: There is nothing 'too broad' about this question. It has two specific yes/no answers, and where the answer is 'yes' there is a limited range of techniques. Ridiculous closure votes and downvotes here.

Comment: It's nothing more than a straw-man question to allow the original poster to simultaneously post ridiculous answers. At least bkail posted an answer that has some merit.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels That may or may not be so, but it doesn't make it 'too broad'.

Answer (score 2):

You could use serialization with a random access file, but you'll have to build the infrastructure yourself. There is no way to get the size of serialization without actually serializing.

I assume you want to store multiple serialized objects in the same file, so you'll need to do something like:

1. Store the serialized objects, keeping track of the offsets within the stream until the end, and then write a table of contents at the end of the file. This is similar to the zip file format.

-or-

2. Write "placeholder" bytes for the size, then serialize the object to the stream, then seek back to the placeholder and write the number of bytes actually written.

Answer (score -1):

You could (using java's [ByteArrayOutputStream](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/java_io_bytearrayoutputstream.htm) and [ByteArrayInputStream](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/java_io_bytearrayinputstream.htm)), but it would be a very bad idea. Java's built in object serialization isn't memoryless. ["The objects must be read back from the corresponding ObjectInputstream with the same types and in the same order as they were written."](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) You could get around this by creating a new instance of ObjectOutputStream/ObjectInputStream for each object you write/read, but that would make your file excessively large.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream);

        objectOutputStream.writeObject(1);
        System.out.println(byteArrayOutputStream.size());
        byteArrayOutputStream.reset();

        objectOutputStream.writeObject(2);
        System.out.println(byteArrayOutputStream.size());
        byteArrayOutputStream.reset();

        objectOutputStream.writeObject(2);
        System.out.println(byteArrayOutputStream.size());
        byteArrayOutputStream.reset();

        objectOutputStream.writeObject(3);
        System.out.println(byteArrayOutputStream.size());
        byteArrayOutputStream.reset();

        objectOutputStream.close();
    }
}
```

Output

- 81
- 10
- 5
- 10

Comment: Thats a rather short answer, to add to this: you can wrap a ByteArrayOutputStream into a ObjectOutputStream. With this construct you can serialize your object to byte[]s. Now you can use any encoding you want to stuff those byte arrays into the file. And the size of the array is the one you care about.