# Random access to an android asset

Tags: java, android, random, inputstream, assets

I am wondering about how to get random access to an android asset. The AssetManager class offers the method "open" and you can pass AssetManager.ACCESS_RANDOM to that method. The documentation says, you kann seek forward and backward in the file (especially seeking backward is what I need), whenn passing ACCESS_RANDOM.
However, the open method always returns an InputStream object, no matter which access mode was requested.
So my question is: how can I call seek methods on that InputStream that does not offer such methods? To which class must I cast the InputStream? I've been searching the web for that problem for some time now, but I could not find anything that helped me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [this source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/android-4.2.2_r1/core/java/android/content/res/AssetManager.java), the method `open(String fileName, int accessMode)` actually returns an `AssetInputStream`.

I did not test it, but you might be able to cast the `InputStream` of the `open()` method to an `AssetInputStream`, which [offers the methods](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.AssetInputStream.html) you are looking for. In particular, the `skip(long n)` method will allow you to skip the first `n` bytes of the file.

You can give it a try and see if it works.

EDIT: if you are looking for a completely random access to the file, I guess it's just not possible. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17494842/1367571) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't see any "seek"-like methods even in  `AssetInputStream`. Or are there some tomatoes on my eyes? :D

Comment: I'm sorry, for a moment I forgot that you also wanted to be able to go backwards. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Copy assets file to cache/temp, then open it for random access, something like this (add errors/write error handling)

```
File outputDir = context.getCacheDir();
File destFile = new File(outputDir, "asset_filename");
OutputStream dest = new FileOutputStream(destFile, true);
InputStream src = context.getAssets().open("asset_directory/asset_filename", ACCESS_STREAMING);
byte[] buff = new byte[100*1024];
for(;;)
{
    int cnt = src.read(buff);
    if(cnt <= 0)
        break;
    dest.write(buff, 0, cnt);
}
dest.flush();
dest.close();
assetFile = new RandomAccessFile(destFile, "r");
```